# Python Selenium - getting 'ElementNotVisibleException' error when trying to click on link

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to perform this action with the code below. It should go to https://www.google.co.jp/ and click on the `YouTube` link on the side menu.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
google=driver.get("https://www.google.co.jp/")
youtube=WebDriverWait(driver,300)
.until(EC.presence_of_element_located
((By.XPATH,".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]    /div[3]/center/input[2]")))
youtube.click()
```

It returns this error:

```
[[ElementNotVisibleException]] ERROR
```

Comment: No problem about the language. What you wrote was already understandable. I improved it a bit and removed the apology at the start now that the grammar is OK. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the element to be clickable, using [element_to_be_clickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) :

```
.until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]    /div[3]/center/input[2]")) );
```

If that does not work I would reccomend verifying that you are using the correct selector, or incrementing wait time.